# Is helping verbs (is or was) necessary?

Tags: verbs, past-simple, past-continuous

I have a few questions related to the below sentence.

1. Are "describing" and "having" main verbs of this sentence?
2. If so, should they be preceded with "be" (is or was) verbs?
3. If not, what type of verbs are they?

> First, only 35 percent maintained a web presence. Of those
>   that did, only 4 percent ***had*** accurate information about their plan broken down by country and ***describing*** their society building initiatives, while still ***having*** no information on local advocacy efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think only "had" is the main verb.
2. The sentence is correct already. Nothing needs to be changed.
3. The following are three *participle phrases*:

> **broken down** by country
>
> **describing** their society building
>   initiatives
>
> **having** no information on local advocacy efforts

All three describe the "plan."

You can read more about participle phrases here:

```
http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm
```